# Dropdown menu not showing right

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

my problem is that when I try to show my dropdown menu under "**Departamentos**" its kinda to the left... not in the right **position** under Departamentos...

I try for hours but nothing, What could be the problem??

[LINK TO THE WEBSITE](http://arojas.dinterweb.com/colono/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `#mainNav li` from `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;`. Just tried in firebug, menu moves to the right place.

The problem is that with `display:block` or `display:inline` `li` has zero width (despite inner content) and thus all `li` elements are shifted to the left. `display:inline-block` makes it stretch to incorporate inner content.

You can see the area element takes highlighted if you move mouse over it in html tab in firebug.